# Bitmap.SetPixel(x,y, Color) too slow

Tags: .net, bitmap

So currently I'm creating a 1000x1000 bitmap and it's spending about .3 seconds simply calling the Bitmap.SetPixel() function.

I'm actually only drawing probably 50% of the pixels so it's more like 500,000 call to setpixel.  While that does seem like a lot of calls, OTOH video games are do alot more and push many many more pixels (some of them procedureally generated).

Obviously Bitmap.SetPixel isn't optimized for speed, but if I needed to update a bitmap 20-30 times a second to get decent animation, this is way to slow, so what are my options?

Comment: I would use your own buffer, then "blit" it to the Bitmap. Sorry, I don't actually know the code solution myself, but I wouldn't SetPixel on each pixel, I'd write to my own buffer (or get access to its buffer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bob Powell has an excellent [tutorial](http://web.archive.org/web/20150330113356/http://bobpowell.net:80/lockingbits.aspx) on accessing pixel maps directly in memory.

Comment: This helped me too.  The key is using Bitmap.LockBits, Bitmap.UnlockBits.

Comment: That link is the unrecommended malware and SPAM sites!

Comment: Done: web archive to replace malware site.

Answer (score 3):

FastPixel?: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/FastPixel.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Modern blockbuster video games do all the pixel setting behind the scenes in hardware; they give the hardware a buffer of geometries and the highly parallelized hardware does all the math. OpenGL and DirectX are APIs for talking to the hardware.

Search [gamedev.net](http://www.gamedev.net) for some tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend [FastBitmap](http://www.vcskicks.com/fast-image-processing.php):

```
FastBitmap fb = new FastBitmap(b);
fb.LockImage();

...

fb.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Red);

...

fb.UnlockImage();
```